# Ambiguous column name in rawQuery select statement

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am running the following command and I am getting ambiguous column name for the following columns

```
Cursor cursor = getWritableDatabase().rawQuery("select ((odometer) - y.odometer) / (gallons) as mpg from gasLog x, gasLog y where y.odometer = (select max(z.odometer) from gasLog z where z.odometer < (odometer))", null);
```

column odometer, gallons, odometer

I've tried changing it to 'odometer' instead of (odometer) however then it doesnt return anything.  What do I need to do to get it to identify that column correctly?

I believe I also tried gasLog.odometer a while ago and that did not work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have a subselect from the same table but you don't use aliases. This way SQLite can't tell which fields are you referring to in your subselect: your original select's fields (x or y) or the subselect's fields. Using aliases in your subselect as well will solve this problem.

Comment: thank you, that points me in the right direction.  I dont exactly understand it because I am new to SQL but after a few googles i think I am headed in the right direction

Comment: I think that you need a decent SQL tutorial then. Pay extra attention to parts with **joins**, **aliases** and **subqueries**.